# How do I add vertices on a segment in QGIS 3.9.? Double-clicking doesn't work

Tags: qgis, snapping, vertices, segment

I tried adding vertices to segments of a polygon by double-clicking on the segment, but instead of adding a node, the nearest node was moved to the double-click. Clicking on the cross doesn't work either as this is only visible in longer segments.

Comment: When the cross is visible, does clicking on it add a new vertex?

Comment: Yes, it does. Unfortunately crosses are only visible on longer segments.

Comment: Zoom in until the segment in question is long enough for the cross to appear. It's an annoying new "feature" of the way the vertex editor tool works in QGIS 3. It helps if  "snapping" is turned off, otherwise you end up editing your existing vertices when you didn't mean to. Check out [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278226/81764) where I explain the changes to the vertex editor from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3.